# nvd3.js - show unique text per symbol on user interaction

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, nvd3.js, scatter-plot

I am trying to to have a unique value displayed per scatter plot symbol whenever the mouse moves over it ( or user clicks it) using nvd3.js. In the code [here](http://nvd3.org/examples/scatter.html), I am able to get a unique value per group and not per symbol.

I think it has to do with some tooltip configuration.

```
//Configure how the tooltip looks.
chart.tooltipContent(function(key) {
    return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>';
});
```

But am not sure as to how to modify it per symbol and not per group.

The example is [here](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav).

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [custom tooltip on cumulativeLineChart in nvd3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319732/custom-tooltip-on-cumulativelinechart-in-nvd3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what you want the unique text to be, but you could make it the node's position for example:

```
chart.tooltipContent(function(key, xval, yval) {
  return '<h3>' + xval + "," + yval + '</h3>';
});
```

Comment: I have a text - unique book name for each symbol. It is a separate array with the size equal to the number of symbols. So should I push that information also in ` data.push({
  key: 'Group1',
  values: []
 });`

Comment: The fourth argument to the tooltip content function has a `.pointIndex` member that should can use to index into that array.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. Could you please answer this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746731/nvd3-scatter-plot-line-chart-with-2-y-axes