# How do I append a total value to title of a nvd3 stacked area chart?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Consider this chart:

http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html

When the mouse is over a particular point, a interactive HTML table shows up with all the y-category values corresponding to the x-value. I would like the sum of all the y-category values to be shown in the title of the table as well. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to a title for a NVD3.js graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459585/how-to-a-title-for-a-nvd3-js-graph)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the title of the HTML table that shows up on mouseover event, not the chart title itself.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319732/custom-tooltip-on-cumulativelinechart-in-nvd3/17950616#17950616).

Answer (score 0):

Although not an answer to putting it into the title, the latest version of the `stackedAreaChart` does have a `showTotalInTooltip` flag which defaults to `true`. With the flag set to `true` the sum of the y-category values is shown at the foot of the table - if the chart is not in expanded mode. The `totalLabel` property defaults to `TOTAL`, so you if you prefer a different label you can change it.